# SQL Server 2012 Express version in registry

Tags: sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-express

I have an installation code which checks the version of the SQL Server installed by reading the version number from the registry key

```
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion 
-> current version.
```

I installed SQL Server 2012 Express and this key does not exist.

SQL Server 2012 (non-express) does have this key.

Before I go and change my code to actually run a query to get the version - is there some other registry key which holds the express version number?

Thank you.

Comment: Does any answer here help? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e31cddc9-b927-45d8-a848-28e1bdf3aea0/registry-keys-to-check-for-sql-server-2008-r2-express?forum=sqlgetstarted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go check this key for the list of installed **instances** on your machine:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL
```

This will list all available instance. Those are again names of a registry key, so if you find a key of `SQLEXPRESS`, it will have a string value - in my case, it's `MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS`.

With that value, again look in the registry for:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\(instance-name)
```

This registry subtree has a lot of information about this particular instance, including (in the `Setup` subtree) information about the version and such

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do by simple querying (not going to registry):

```
select serverproperty('edition')
```

Result on express instance:

```
Express Edition
```

Result on non-express instance:

```
Enterprise Edition (64-bit)
```

More information can be retrieved using `select @@version`